# Jmockit code coverage stopped working after we upgraded gradle to V3.3

Tags: gradle, jmockit, maven-surefire-plugin, gradle-plugin

After, we upgraded gradle to v3.3 , jmockit code coverage stopped working. I tried to use javaagent as explained in http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html, but still no luck. Did anyone faced this issue and how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, resolved it myself , weird but upgrading to gradle 3.5 solved it